# How to debug pyramid test cases in pycharm 3

Tags: pyramid, pycharm

I am evaluating Pycharm 3 for pyramid development. My question is how can I debug / set breakpoint pyramid test cases in pycharm 3.

To run test cases, I give following command

```
python setup.py test -q
```

I configure this in pycharm, to run test cases from pycharm. But If I set debug pointer / breakpoint, control wont stop. It run test cases without stopping any breakpoint.

Thanks
Aniruddha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See PyCharm documentation on [Breakpoints](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/breakpoints-2.html) and [Debugging](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/debugging.html).

Comment: @Aniruddha would you please tell me how did solve your problem by looking at documentations?